# Creating grid usonf Pandas for repetitive X-Y elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a text file containing columns A,B and C with each row containing 1000+ elements as shown in image 1. Values in column C are output from a function with inputs as A and B.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2x4D.png)

Most values in A and B are repetitive.

I want to create a grid as in image 2 using pandas such that the X-axis is A and Y-axis B with corresponding values as C. C should be output as a list of lists.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJEZj.png)

I could not find a method for this. Request help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to pivot your dataframe. Try:

```
out = df.pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='C')
```

But if you raise a `ValueError` about duplicate entries, it's because you have more than one value for the same cell (A, B). In this case, you have to take a decision to keep only one value: you can take the `mean`, `min`, `max`, `first`, `last` or whatever you want that aggregate values.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to only print out only the values parameter in df.pivot?

Comment: `out = df.pivot('A', 'B', 'C')`?